# JavaScript Event Loop Queues Terminology

Tags: javascript, node.js, message-queue, event-loop, asynchronous-javascript

I've been reading a lot of tutorials as well as posts in StackOverflow regarding **Event Loop** in Javascript (Browser/NodeJS) and i'm currently a bit consfused on the terminology used when referring to the Event Loop Queues.

So my questions are the following :

- From my understanding, **Message Queue** & **Event Queue** are
  general terms referring to both the **Micro** & **Macro** **Task
  Queues** simultaneously. Does this hold true?
- Is the term **Callback Queue** also generaly referring to both
  **Micro** & **Macro Task Queues** ?

Comment: Try to limit to one question only. In the meanwhile have a read of [HTML Standard - Event Loops](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#event-loops)